# Java Map value access

Tags: java, generics

I am more or less a Java noob and wanted some feedback on a method I wrote. I wanted to avoid the pattern of checking if a key exists before accessing the value and throw an exception if the key does not exist.

Instead of doing this:

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    return map.get(key)
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

everywhere in the code, I came up with the following solution:

```
class Utils {
    public static <K, V> V safeGet(final K key, Map<K,V> map) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            return map.get(key);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this method? Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: Since you're putting it in a separate function any way, wouldn't it be better to return a boolean indicating whether the get was successful?  This way you can handle the error without throw an exception.

Comment: I think that you did very well. I don't find anything wrong with this method and I don't see any problems with this approach.

Comment: If I have to return a boolean, I might as well return a map.get(key) and do a null check before using the value returned.

Comment: Please provide a real-world example usage where you think this function would be advantageous.

Comment: As 200_success mentioned: I have a hard time to really see a good reason to use that. It looks like, somewhere in your app, you get a key from somewhere, which you shouldn't have received in the first place. And: You might want to check the `Optional` type.

Comment: Right, throwing an exception is the right choice for me here. But yes, in case I was forced to return something, I would have just gone ahead with an `Optional<V>` as the return type which will likely suggest a `isPresent` check before using that contained value.

Answer (score 1):

As some other stated I am also convinced that there is less or no beneficial usage for enriching a simple associative map to throw an exception if an element is not found.

I suggest to go with a use case specific exception handling as the context is important where a not available value is an exceptional case.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         if (map.containsKey(key)) {
>             return map.get(key);
>         } else {
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException();
>         }
> ```

The `map.get` method does a `contains` call as part of it.  So you could do

```
        V value = map.get(key);

        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        return value;
```

This changes the result slightly.  The original could return a null value if the [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) contains key/value pair where the value is null.  If that is desirable, then your original code might be better.

But if that's a bug, and you only want to return non-null values, then this code is better.  It explicitly checks for the bad result.

It's unclear what the compiler does with the original code.  Perhaps it optimizes out the extra `containsKey` check.  Or perhaps it does the same calculations twice, unnecessarily.  This might be more efficient.  Or maybe the compiler fixes it.  Someone would have to look at the generated byte-code to see.

Comment: Yep, I will likely save one additional lookup by getting the value directly and doing a null check instead of containsKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getOrDefault` method to require only one lookup for most map implementations (esp. important for concurrent maps that may contain `null` values to ensure reliable results).

```
private static final Object NOT_PRESENT = new Object();
public static <K, V> V safeGet(K key, Map<K, V> map) {
    Map m = map; Object v;
    if ((v = m.getOrDefault(key, NOT_PRESENT)) == NOT_PRESENT)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return (V) v;
}
```